# Phonegap Audio Don't get proper link

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I've been trying to play audio in my PhoneGap android application.

The audio works fine in browser but working in apps.
So, I tried following codes, but it didn't help.

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="file:///android_asset/audio/Surah An Nas.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
```

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="file:///android_asset/www/audio/Surah An Nas.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
```

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="audio/Surah An Nas.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
```

But none of them worked.

Here's the git repo link.
[PhoneGap Demo App](https://gitlab.com/illusionist3886/phonegap-demo/tree/master)

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename the audio file names by removing the space. Example: write SurahAnNas instead of Surah An Nas. & then build apk again. It worked for me. try yours.

Comment: That didn't work for me. What was the url you put in <audio src="filepath/filename"> attribute